# How to extend entityreference field by another custom field?

Tags: entities, views

I want to add another field, which needs to be accessible by views (for display and ordering), to the [entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) table field_data_field_FIELDNAME. Structure of that table is:

- entity_type VARCHAR(128)
- bundle VARCHAR(128)
- deleted TINYINT(4)
- entity_id INT(10)
- revision_id INT(10)
- language VARCHAR(32)
- delta INT(10)
- field_FIELDNAME_target_id INT(10)

I want to have a column storing DateTime information here, so I can attach information about when this reference was added/ updated for that referenced entity. There also needs to be a way to save the newly added field directly in the array structure for that reference such as:

```
$node->field_reference['und'][] = array(
  'target_id' => 123,
  'my_new_column' => '2014-03-13 15:29:29'
);
```

I know I could solve this by using [field_collections](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) or [relation](https://drupal.org/project/relation) module, but both would cause significant performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

Gave an approach here https://www.drupal.org/node/2001822#comment-9165509

Hope that it will work for you

Comment: thank you, you should probably post the contents in your answer on stackexchange as well to help others, luckily I managed to finish this task a few month ago - but didnt have time to answer my own question. code is here: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/baumeier.it/2078043

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, even when linking to your own post. Keep the link, but summarize it here, and you'll have my upvote. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer